# Import external file content into handlebar

Tags: css, handlebars.js, assemble

I hope someone can give me a hint.
I would like to import content from one file into my handlebar file. Is it possible? 
In my case, it is an css/scss file (e.g. reset.css) which stylings I want to import into my handlebar file (styleReset.hbs).

The "styleReset.hbs" should looks kind of like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    <!-- import of reset.css content -->
</style>
```

P.S. I don't want use the -tag

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to import the external css file into your handlebars .hbs file (i.e- Template engine).
**Follow these steps :**

- First create a folder public under which place your css
  folder, which content all your css files. For ex folder structure would be - public/css/style.css  (Note: This public folder contains all your static files like css, images, etc)
- Register your public folder to express in your .js file by `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`
- Now you can import external css file in handlerbars template file
  by `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">`

[image]

Comment: Thank you -- the 2nd bullet is the part I was stuck on.  I forgot that my server needs to be able to serve files other than the main html routes.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can't import files with handlebars, only partials. You could precompile your reset.css as if it was a handlebars partial and include that with `{{> filename}}`.

Without knowing your build setup I don't think I can go into more detail.

http://handlebarsjs.com/precompilation.html

(Personally I'd use [sass to import my reset.css](http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-5) to some main stylesheet that I include in the page.)

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to have a 'main' layout too, that can include header and footer.

```
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({
  extname: '.hbs',
  defaultLayout: 'main'
}))
app.set('view engine', '.hbs')
```

Also, if you are using the module, "express-handlebars"(not "hbs"). You can set your extension name too.

Answer (score 0):

1)In order to use your .css file in handlebars, file should be registered for use in app.js/server.js file shown bellow.

```
app.use("/bootstrap",express.static(__dirname+"/node_modules/bootstrap/dist"))
```

2)import the file in your handlebar file as given bellow image(it works for both main layout and child layout.


i) In Main Layout File
[image: In MainLayout]


ii) In Child Layout
[image]

Comment: Hi, It would be great if just put the snippet in the answer itself, so other users don't have to navigate through the links.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**It's working after adding it**

```
// app.js file
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

public/
      ├── style.css/

// htm file
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
```

Answer (score -1):

```
index.js 
public:
   style.css
views:
   index.hbs

Inside index.js
   var express=require('express');
   var app=express(); 
   var hbs = require('hbs');
   app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
   app.use(express.static('.'));
Inside index.hbs
<head>
    <link href="./public/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```